# Show notification every 1 minute Android

Tags: android, jobintentservice, notificationservices

I want to run a service whenever the user opens the app and then make it run as long as the app is installed for every 1 minute. The service will check if there are new orders by making an API call and if there are then it'll show a notification.

I have done some research and found JobIntentService and Broadcast Reciever are what I need to use for my problem but I am not able to put them together to make it work. I'll really appreciate if someone can give a detailed solution. I also want to know if there is something better than this for my problem? Below is the code I managed to write.

Background Service

```
public class BackgroundService extends JobIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = BackgroundService.class.getName();

    private static final int JOB_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
        enqueueWork(context, BackgroundService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + "#onCreate");
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Running in background!");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundService.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + "#onHandleWork!");

        APIInterface service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIInterface.class);
        Call<List<OrdersModel>> call = service.getAllOrders(Services.CONSUMER_KEY,Services.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<OrdersModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<OrdersModel>> call,@NonNull Response<List<OrdersModel>> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    for (OrdersModel orders : response.body()){
                        if (orders.getStatus().equals("processing")){
                            sendNotification("#" + orders.getNumber());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<OrdersModel>> call,@NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + "Network Error!");
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendNotification(String title) {

        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GetOrdersActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentText("New Order")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

        Log.d("GoParty", "Notification sent ----- ");
    }
}
```

BroadcastReciever

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
        BackgroundService.enqueueWork(context, notificationIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you want to ruin your users battery, you might want to look into push notifications instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it should work. The app on the mobile device must preserve battery life. Polling doesn't do that well. What you want is a push notification, where the server is playing the active part. You can achieve that with Firebase Cloud Messaging, for example.

Have a look: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?authuser=0

The server is responsible for knowing when a new order is available and can act in the exact right moment to send a push notification to the client app.